# How to debug JS in a new opened window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I have a functionality that open a new window. In this new window there is js code that I need to debug when the windows opens i.e debug immediately after the window opens. For example I want to debug on load function or something like that.

How can I keep the debugger opened or Open it automatically and make it stop on the break points when the new windows opens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programatically trigger a breakpoint by using [the `debugger;` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint in your onload handler and reload the page.

Comment: Danke very much .. :)